# How to count zero pixels between consecutive non-zero ones in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

From a grayscale image I obtained its non-zero pixel coordinates using this line of code in OpenCV:

```
cv::Mat nonZeroCoordinates;
cv::findNonZero(image, nonZeroCoordinates);
```

Now, I want to count the zero pixels between two consecutive non-zero elements in `image`. But should I move through columns or rows first? For instance, if I have non-zero pixels at point (30, 20) and (30, 23) in a 40x40 mat, and moving through columns give me 2 zero pixels between them, and moving through rows gives  me (39-30) + 40 + 40 + 29 = 118 pixels. Through which way should I count these pixels correctly? Is there any better way then just nested loop for this purpose? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure you mean for the second point to be (30,23) I could be wrong though

Comment: depends on YOUR definition of "number of pixels between consecutive non-zero ones"... what do you want to do with that value, or what should be the meaning of that value?... more efficient is to count within a single row first (because of caching because of Mat memory layout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should fit a line over the endpoints and count the zero pixels under it. OpenCV has a [LineIterator](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#lineiterator) class which you can make a 8-connected or 4-connected line from (30, 20) to (30, 23) and check the values.

Comment: I saw on the documentation that it is used for 8-bit 3-channel image, so is it also correct to use it for single channel grayscale image?

Comment: I think it should work, except that `it` will points to `uchar` pixels instead of `cv::Vec3b`.